# magento2 ko issue in cart-items.js

Tags: magento2, html, knockoutjs

I try to classify the items by type in checkout order summary.

I added the classifyItems function in cart-items.js

```
    classifyItems: function()  {
        var ItemsTab=[];
        var Items = this.getItems();
        for(var key in Items) {
            var itemType=Items[key].product_type;
            if (typeof ItemsTab[itemType] === 'undefined') {ItemsTab[itemType]=[];}
            ItemsTab[itemType][key]=Items[key];
        }
        console.log('classified items');
        console.log(ItemsTab);
        return ItemsTab;
    }
```

when I do in cart-items.html

```
<div class="content minicart-items" data-role="content">
        <div class="minicart-items-wrapper overflowed">
            <ol class="minicart-items">
                <!-- ko foreach: {data: Object.keys(classifyItems()), as: 'key'} -->
                    <li class="product-item"><!-- ko text: key--><!-- /ko --></li>
```

the different product types are displayed, but when I want to go further :

```
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: Object.keys(classifyItems()), as: 'key'} -->        
            <li class="product-item"><!-- ko text: key--><!-- /ko --></li>
            <!-- ko foreach: classifyItems().key-->
                    <li class="product-item">
                        <div class="product">
                            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.elems() -->
                            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                    </li>                               
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
```

I have got an error : classifyItems is not defined

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `foreach`, then new scope will be created.

Acoording ko.js [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html):

You can use `$parent` to refer to data from outside the `foreach`, e.g.

```
<h1 data-bind="text: blogPostTitle"></h1>
<ul data-bind="foreach: likes">
    <li>
        <b data-bind="text: name"></b> likes the blog post <b data-bind="text: $parent.blogPostTitle"></b>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your case:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: $parent.classifyItems()[key]-->
```

But you can use already exist item instead of reloading of `classifyItems()`

Comment: thank you Max for your answer. how can I use item instead of recalling each time "classifyItems"? furhtermore, at the end I have <!-- ko foreach: $parent.elems() -->
                            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->. As I have several foreach loop, I still have $parent.elems() is undefined... and $parent.$parent does not work...

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html you can use `$parents` array for access to parent of parent